# Codeigniter internal server error load model

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

I have this model

```
<?php
class Votante_model extends CI_Model{
    var $departamento = '';
    var $municipio = '';
    var $puesto = '';
    var $direccion_puesto = '';
    var $fecha_inscripcion = '';
    var $mesa = '';

    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function getVotanteJSON($cedula){
        $retorno = '';
        $this->db->save_queries = true;


        $this->db->select('nom_dpto, nom_mpio, nom_puesto, mesa');
        $this->db->join('divipol', 'censo.cod_dpto = cod_dpto');
        $this->db->join('divipol', 'censo.cod_mpio = cod_mpio');
        $this->db->join('divipol', 'censo.cod_puesto = cod_puesto');
        $this->db->where('censo.cedula = ',$cedula);

        $query = $this->db->get('censo');

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
            $row = $query->row_array();

            $departamento = $row['nom_dpto'];
            $municipio = $row['nom_mpio'];
            $puesto = $row['nom_puesto'];
            $direccion_puesto = '';
            $fecha_inscripcion = '';
            $mesa = $row['mesa'];

            $retorno = '{"error":"", "codigo": 1,"departamento": "'.$departamento.'", "municipio": "'.$municipio.'", "puesto": "'.$puesto.'", "direccion": "Cll 64A", "fecha": "19910825", "mesa": '.$mesa.'}'; 
        }else{
            $retorno = '{"error": "No hay datos", "codigo": -1}';
        }

        return $retorno;
    }
   }
```

and this controller

```
<?php
class Datos extends CI_Controller{

public function __construct(){
parent::__construct();
}


public function index(){
echo "<p>" . $this->db->last_query(); . "</p>";
echo "<div>" . $this->db->_error_message() . "</div>";
}


Public function votante($cedula){
$this->load->model('votante_model');
$data['json']= $this->Votante->getVotanteJSON($cedula);
$this->load->view('json_view',$data);

}


}
```

and this view

```
<?php

$this->output->set_header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo $json;
?>
```

when I call a controller throws this error: 500 Internal Server Error  and no error on logs neither apache logs. What's wrong??
Htaccess is ok, Deny from all

Thanks in advance

Comment: how you are calling your controller?

Comment: calling controller:  http://127.0.0.1:8040/reg/index.php/datos/votante/509956

Comment: 1) double cross your htaccess file. most of the time 500 error is because of that only. 2) try to exit in controller and check it is coming in there or not

Comment: It comming to controller, the line throws error is $this->load->model('votante_model'); but I don't know why... Modifing htaccess with 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]   but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the model:

```
$data['json']= $this->votante_model->getVotanteJSON($cedula);
// not this:
$data['json']= $this->Votante->getVotanteJSON($cedula);
```

As it is now, you're calling the method from within the method.

Comment: Not work, 500 Internal Server Error. I thinking put single class with the method and call it. Not extend from CI_Model. But if I put select into Controller, not working, same error.

Comment: I think we agree though that if you want to use the `votante_model`, going `$data['json']= $this->Votante->etc...`is incorrect. Right?

Comment: yes I agree that call ->Votante is incorrect, but with ->votante_model  neither work